# Get values from a Array in a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

My ambition is to have a Dictionary that contains (among other things) an array and being able to get out the values of that array.

```
var total: Int = 0;
let dice:[NSTextField:NSArray] = [
        d4Amount:[d4OE, 4],
        d6Amount:[d6OE, 6],
    ];

for (die, dieArray) in dice
{
    let button:NSButton = dieArray[0] as! NSButton;
    let num:Int = dieArray[1] as! Int;
    total += DoRoll(die, oe: button, max: num);
}
```

In the above the line "let button:NSButton = dieArray[0]..." get's the error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT and the program fails.
First I only had the line:

```
total += DoRoll(die, oe: dieArray[0] as! NS Button, max: dieArray[1] as! Int);
```

Which didn't either work (quite obviously), but however when I do this, it works...

```
total += DoRoll(d4Amount, oe: d4OE, max: 4);
```

It works perfectly.

Any ideas??

The function DoRoll looks like this (which should not be relevant):

```
private func DoRoll(amount: NSTextField, oe: NSButton, max: Int) -> Int
{
    let nrRolls: Int! = Int(amount.stringValue);
    var total: Int = 0;
    if(nrRolls != nil && nrRolls != 0)
    {
        OutputText.string = OutputText.string! + "Now rolling d" + String(max) + ": ";
        for(var i: Int = 0; i < nrRolls; i++)
        {
            var randomNr: Int, specialMax: Int;
            var textStr: String = "";

            specialMax = max;
            if(max >= 100)
            {
                if(max > 100)
                {
                    specialMax = 995;
                }
                else if(max > 99)
                {
                    specialMax = 95;
                }
                else
                {
                    specialMax = max - 1;
                }
            }

            repeat
            {
                randomNr = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max))) + 1;
                total += randomNr;
                if(textStr != "") { textStr = textStr + "+"; }
                textStr = textStr + String(randomNr);
            } while(oe.state == NSOnState && randomNr >= specialMax)

            OutputText.string = OutputText.string! + textStr + " ";
        }
        OutputText.string = OutputText.string! + "\n";
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I know, my Array has different types of values. It's intended. This is supposed to be an exercise in a bit of extreme array handling.

Comment: What is `DoRoll` ? can you provide more info?

Comment: Sure. My biggest problem is that the extraction of the values from the array doesn't work and that is my questions so I thought it was really irrelevant, but here is the function:

Comment: Crap... Cannot attach the function to a comment but now you have it in the original post.

Comment: I copied ur code to Xcode and I didn't found any issue from the code. Could you check your `d4OE` and `d6OE`? I got same issue as you when I declare both variables wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know what I did wrong.

This is not at all a case of error in the code above but in the naming of items in the project. I had several different D4Amount in the same project in the View and thus that was why it crashed.

Sorry to bother you.